# Protractor not working for Safari on windows 7

Tags: safari, cross-browser, protractor, windows-7-x64

I am trying to run protractor e2e test cases on safari with windows 7. its throwing following error:

```
[10:27:59] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[10:27:59] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:28:00] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.1.69.133:65294/wd/hub
[10:28:01] E/launcher - The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{
ceptSslCerts=true, trustAllSSLCertificates=true, name=safari-tests, count=1, browserName=safari, directConnect=false, sharedTestFiles=true}]
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'DENXD7OShore41p', ip: '10.1.69.133', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[10:28:01] E/launcher - WebDriverError: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver can't create a new driver instance for
apabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, trustAllSSLCertificates=true, name=safari-tests, count=1, browserName=safari, directConnect=false, sharedTestFile
true}]
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'DENXD7OShore41p', ip: '10.1.69.133', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at WebDriverError (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:639:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:538:13)
    at client_.send.then.response (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:472:11)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
    at asyncRun (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25)
    at c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:329:24)
    at Builder.build (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:458:24)
    at Local.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:37:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:198:43)
    at c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:277:30
    at _fulfilled (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (c:\Git\operator\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[10:28:01] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Here is the code for my protractor.conf.js file. I made some changes in config after error, Like i added selenium address and removed acceptSslCerts=true, trustAllSSLCertificates=true but after that i am getting the same error.

```
/*global jasmine */
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'safari',
        name: 'safari-tests',
        directConnect: false,
        seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
  },
maxInstances: 1,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
    isVerbose : true,
    includeStackTrace : true,
    print: function() {}
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  onPrepare: function() {
     require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  }
};
```

Does it require some other configuration to run it on Safari.

Comment: This is very likely an issue with your config. It's trying to use `EdgeDriver`, but _should_ be using `SafariDriver`. Please post your config

Comment: @Brine I have added code of my config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari for Windows was [discontinued years ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/94010/79321) and installing the old Safari 5 exe that's still around won't help you achieve anything useful regarding test automation.

So never download Safari from other that [the official site](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/) else chances are you are getting a Trojan in it.

You can only test Safari using a Mac OSX or you can try Sauce Labs / [BrowserStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41726570/511069) / Testing Bot / other cloud test providers to test in browsers you don't have installed locally.