# Protractor tests with BrowserStack iOS emulators

Tags: ios, safari, protractor, browserstack

I've already spent much time for it, but still have no significant results.
My protractor tests work fine with browserstack Firefox and Chrome. But with Safari browser they don't. Protractor tests are not executed synchronously in such case, and running tests with synchronization turned off completely messes up all tests too.
Does anyone succeeded with running his protractor tests in Safari on browserStack????

Answer (score 0):

I am able to successfully run on `browserStack` using safari browser. This is my config and it all looks good.

```
   browserstackUser: '******',
    browserstackKey: '*******',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'safari',
        'shardTestFiles': true,
        'maxInstances': 0
    },
```

Check below console log for browser - OS combination

Output on Console:

```
[23:40:16] I/browserstack - Using BrowserStack selenium server at http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub
[23:40:16] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 13.321 seconds

[23:40:38] I/browserstack - {"automation_session":{"name":null,"duration":null,"os":"OS X","os_version":"Mountain Lion","browser_version":"6.2","browser":"safari","device":null,"status":"done","hashed_id":"554ff4b7f1e3be0207b40d3f4ec49d08c9090f03","reason":null,"build_name":"Untitled Build","project_name":"Untitled Project"}}
[23:40:38] I/browserstack - BrowserStack results available at https://www.browserstack.com/automate/builds/******/sessions/*******
[23:40:54] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[23:40:54] I/launcher - safari #01 passed
Closing report
```

Comment: Do you run your tests with synchronization turned off? (browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;).

Comment: No I dont.. I test an angular application and I need the `synchronization` to be  on

Comment: I also test angular app. But when i try to run tests with synchronization on in Safari all the tests fail with 'angular not defined' and 'protractor synchronization error'. But it doesn't appear for Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Can you run one manual test on browerstack-safari and check if your app is loading properly

Comment: Yes, it loads properly. To make couple tests work, i had to use browser.ignoreSynchronization=true; and each function inside each test i had to place into the control flow manually. Otherwise sequence of test actions is broken.